# Unix function can not called after switch user in shell script

Tags: linux, unix

The below script executing with root user.After switch user Unix function showing error.

### test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
fn_test()
{
echo "This is function"
}
whoami
fn_test
su - oracle<<EOF
whoami
fn_test #This function not called
EOF
exit 0

O/P
root $ ./test.sh
root
This is function
oracle
-ksh[2]: fn_test: not found [No such file or directory]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a confusion on what `su` actually does: you hope it to just swith user when it does start a new process. You can control it with `ps` in an interactive session: you see the original shell, the `su` command, the new shell launched by `su` and the current `ps` command.

As a shell function is local to the shell it cannot be used in a (grand) child shell.

The best that you can hope is to pass something through the environment. I know that aliases can be put there unsure for functions. Moreover, this is absolutely shell dependant and might not be portable.